# Batch File to Convert DOC Files to TXT

Tags: batch-file

I Have batch code listed in a password protected word file (so no one can edit my code) and i need a .bat file that can convert the code i have listed in there, to a .txt file that i can have it read. If you know a way to make a .bat file that can read a word doc, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you only want to 'protect' (by obscurity) your code from modification, why not simply use something like `bat2exe` or `bat2com` etc? Or.. using simple file-permissions to add write-protection?

Comment: Do you have the password?

Answer (score 3):

Using a (tested) hybrid batchscript (that encapsulates JScript):

```dos
@if (0)==(1) REM BatchScript: 
:INIT
 @ECHO OFF & CLS
 SET DOC=C:\Some folder\tst.doc
 SET TXT=C:\Some other folder\res.txt
 SET PWD=MySecretPass
:MAIN
 cscript //NoLogo //E:JScript "%~f0" /inp:"%DOC%" /outp:"%TXT%" /pass:"%PWD%"
 notepad "%TXT%"
 GOTO ENDBAT
:ENDBAT
 ECHO        Press any key to exit...&PAUSE>NUL
 GOTO :EOF
@end // JScript:

 var FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 ,   HND = FSO.CreateTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Named('outp'))
 ,   APP = WScript.CreateObject('Word.Application')
 ,   DOC, str
 ;
 APP.Visible=false;  //hide word
 DOC = APP.Documents       // access interface
          .Open( WScript.Arguments.Named('inp')        //file location
               , false                                 //ConfirmConversions
               , true                                  //ReadOnly
               , false                                 //AddToRecentFiles
               , WScript.Arguments.Named('pass') || '' //PasswordDocument
             //,   //PasswordTemplate
             //,   //Revert
             //,   //WritePasswordDocument
             //,   //WritePasswordTemplate
             //,   //Format
             //,   //Encoding
             //,   //Visible
             //,   //OpenConflictDocument
             //,   //OpenAndRepair
             //,   //DocumentDirection
             //,   //NoEncodingDialog
               );
 str=new String(DOC.Content);                //grab content
 str=str.replace(/\r\n|\r/g,'\r\n')+'\r\n';  //cleanup line-endings
 HND.Write( str );                           //write the file
 HND.Close();  //close file handle
 DOC.Close();  //close word doc
 APP.quit(0);  //don't forget to close word
```

- Save this as a batchscript, replacing the hardcoded inputfile `DOC`, outputfile `TXT` and password `PWD`. See npocmaka's answer to alter this to accepting arguments on the batchscript call.
- Instead of running the resulting txt-file through `notepad` you might want to call the batchscript directly.
- Also you might want to delete the extracted batchfile under the `:ENDBAT` label.
- Also, (to keep it simple and to the *core*) there is no error-checking provided.
- Lastly, it requires MS Word (starting at Office 2000) to be installed.

**Usage:** simply run it however you please.

**UPDATE:**
After comparing notes and doing tests in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60808/discussion-between-gitaarlab-and-npocmaka), npocmaka and I concluded that if one uses word's [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx), the safest bet is using type `2`: `wdFormatText`. More about that in npocmaka's updated answer.
My example (writing a new file using the FileSystemObject) shows a simpler way of post-processing the fetched text *and* doesn't update word's internal recent file-list (MRU) that otherwise would be updated when word converts saves the file.

Between the both of our answers there is plenty to choose from, so happy mixing!

Comment: +1  , but why do you get the content and write it through a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` . SaveAs method of word.application can save a file in different formats ->http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx

Comment: @npocmaka: Thx. I had problems finding proper documentation (although it was my first idea). On the other hand, I already got the cookie from the jar so it was extra tempting to follow a more familiar path from there on (hence just created a new file using the FileSystemObject). PS, I must admit, I'm still dissecting the core of your answer.

Comment: ready with my jscript edition :-)

Comment: @npocmaka: I see (and am dissecting it to) But I can't upvote twice haha. Fun to see we both similar approach to the hybrid wrapper. Personally I'd shift error-handling more to the JScript part (feels simpler).

Answer (score 1):

See this page:

http://www.abisource.com/wiki/AbiCommand

which describes using the command line options available for AbiWord, including

```
converttotext "file\path\file.doc" "destingation\file.txt"
```

(http://www.abisource.com/download/index.phtml)

A smaller install would probably be http://wvware.sourceforge.net/#wv, but apparently the developer considers those utilities to be "deprecated" and probably not as reliable as using AbiWord.

This just in: see http://github.com/tobya/DocTo

Comment: how does it pass the 'password'?

Comment: Now that is a good question ... and I'm afraid I'm not sure about that. This makes my answer rather poor. If I find an answer, I'll let you know.

Comment: You might consider using a UI automation option -- I'd suggest AutoIt or Sikuli.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a script that I've wrote long ago to save doc(x) to txt](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27486#p27486). And this is  a reworked version that [accepts a password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216319(v=office.12).aspx):

```dos
'>nul 2>&1|| @copy /Y %windir%\System32\doskey.exe '.exe >nul
'&&@echo off && cls &&goto :end_vbs

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = FALSE

'Open doc for reading

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(0),true,true,false,WScript.Arguments.Item(2))

'wdFormatText 2
'wdFormatUnicodeText 7
format = CInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(3) )
WordDoc.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1) ,format 
WordDoc.Close()
WScript.Quit

:end_vbs

'& if "%~1" equ "-help" echo %~n0 word_document  destination password [-unuicode] 
'& if "%~1" equ "" echo word document not given & exit /b 1
'& if not exist "%~f1" echo word document does not exist & exit /b 2
'& if "%~2" equ "" echo destination not given & exit /b 1
'& set "save_as=%~2"
'& if  exist "%~f2" del /s /q "%~f2"
'& if "%~4" equ "-unuicode" ( set "format=7") else ( set "format=2")
'& taskkill /im winword* /f >nul 2>&1
'& cscript /nologo /E:vbscript %~f0 "%~f1" "%save_as%" "%~3" %format% 
'& pause
'& del /q /f '.exe
```

This is a batch/vbscript hybrid and you need to save it as a `.bat`
Note - will need admin permissions to start "invisible" word application.

An example (if file is saved as `doc2txt.bat`)  (it's better to use full paths):

```dos
doc2txt.bat c:\tstpass.docx c:\result\tstpass.txt super_secret_password
doc2txt.bat c:\tstpass.docx c:\result\tstpass.txt super_secret_password -unicode
```

**EDIT** jscript/bat hybrid

```dos
 @if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
     @echo off

     if "%~1" equ "-help" echo %~n0 word_document  destination password [-unuicode|-breaks] 
     if "%~1" equ "" echo %~n0 word_document  destination password [-unuicode]
     if "%~2" equ "" echo destination not given & exit /b 1
     if "%~3" equ "" echo password not given & exit /b 3
     if  exist "%~f2" del /s /q "%~f2"
     if "%~4" equ "-unicode" ( 
        set "format=7"
    ) else (
       if "%~4" equ "-breaks" (
        set "format=3"
    ) else ( 
      set "format=2"
     )
    )

     :: kill winword application to avoid collisions
     taskkill /im winword* /f >nul 2>&1

     if not exist "%~f1" echo word document does not exist & exit /b 2



     cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%~f1" "%~2" %~3 %format%
     exit /b 0

    *****  end comment *********/

 var source_file=WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
 var destination_file=WScript.Arguments.Item(1);

 var confirmConv=false;
 var readOnly=true;
 var addToRecentFiles=false;

 var password=WScript.Arguments.Item(2);

//save format enumaration -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx
// text formats 
//wdFormatText 2
//wdFormatUnicodeText 7
//wdFormatTextLineBreaks 3
 var encoding=parseInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(3));

 var WordApp=new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
 WordApp.Visible = false;

 var WordDoc=WordApp.Documents.Open(source_file,confirmConv,readOnly,addToRecentFiles,password);
 WordDoc.SaveAs(destination_file,encoding);
 WordDoc.Close();
 WScript.Quit();
```

examples:

```dos
doc2txtjs.bat "c:\tstpass.docx" "c:\result\tstpass.txt"  unhackable_password -breaks
doc2txtjs.bat "c:\tstpass2.docx" "c:\result\tstpass2.txt"  unhackable_password -unicode
doc2txtjs.bat "c:\tstpass3.docx" "c:\result\tstpass3.txt"  unhackable_password
```

-breaks/-unicode will save the file respectively with preserved line breaks or in unicode format.You'll need admin permissions again.But as you want to create a bat from doc you dont need to use these additional options.

Comment: Ah, crap, was just finishing of testing my JScript hybrid. Ahh, I'll post it anyway.

Comment: @GitaarLAB I was intended to rewrite this as a jscript too :-)

Comment: let's compare notes (about to hit submit) EDIT: oh, and +1 , duh!

Comment: I don't yet fully get it: `WordDoc.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1) ,format`, but `format = CInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(3) )` and arguments.Item(3) is 'super_secret_password'. How does converting the password string to an int result in the SaveAs SaveFormat?

Comment: @GitaarLAB - windows script host starts to count the arguments from `0`.As I can see in your code you are using named arguments so you don't need to worry about numeration.

Comment: yeah, I just found it: `if "%~4" equ "-unuicode" ( set "format=7") else ( set "format=2")` I also found some explanation (from you) regarding the vbs hybrid: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1700

Comment: will type 7 `wdFormatEncodedText` return UTF8, UTF16 or UTF32 encoding?

Comment: @GitaarLAB - I've just checked the generated files with a hex editor and there is no difference between wdFormatUnicodeText and wdFormatText ...  0_o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60808/discussion-between-gitaarlab-and-npocmaka).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I made a batch program that creates a temporary VBS file that converts it to a BAT file instead of a TXT. Then I executed the Batch file from the converter. Thanks for all your answers though and I saw some useful ideas.  :)